# Best practice of class initialization in python

Tags: python

Hi I am wondering what the best practice is to initialize a class in python, while ensuring that my attributes have the correct datatype.

Shall I initialize my class-attributes with default values or call the checking function?

```
class Foo:
    # Call with default value
    def __init__(self, bar=""):
         self._bar = bar

    # Calling set-function
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self._bar = ""
        self.set_bar(bar)

    def get_bar(self):
        return self._bar

    def set_bar(self, bar):
        if not isinstance(bar, str):
            raise TypeError("bar must be string")
        self._bar = bar

    def del_bar(self):
        self._bar = ""

    bar = property(get_bar, set_bar, del_bar, 'bar')
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `__init__` is missing `self` argument

Comment: If there's a default value, why would you *not* put it in the signature?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code snippet:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, bar=''):
        self.bar = bar

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, bar):
        if isinstance(bar, str):
            self._bar = bar
        else:
            raise TypeError('<bar> has to be of type string')

f = Foo('5') # works fine
g = Foo(5) # raises type error
```

The checking is done even when no argument is provided at the instantiation of the class. So even if you would provide an integer as default argument, it would trigger the exception.

Comment: Is there a difference in using @property and property(get, set, del) as I did?

Comment: @FranzSchwerdtmann: Basically not, but I think the use of decorators makes your intention more clear. And please notice the subtle difference between your code snippet and mine. You use ``self._bar = bar`` inside your ``__init__`` method. This way, you bypass your setter method. Also, you do not need the second ``__init__`` method.